# jQuery: Load background image from css class into variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I load the background-image (url) from a css class into a JavaScript variable (preferably using jQuery) ?

Example:

```
.myCssClass { background-image: url(/images/checkered.gif) no-repeat; }
```

...and now load checkered.gif into a `var CheckeredGraphic = ???` using JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do it is to just ask jQuery what the background image is. If you don't have any elements with class `myCssClass` perhaps just generate one and don't add it to the DOM.

```
var checkeredGraphic = $('<div class="myCssClass"></div>').css("backgroundImage");
```

I haven't tested that, but if it doesn't work, perhaps add it to the body with a large negative margin so it doesn't render on screen.

That line above will return `url(/images/checkered.gif)` so then you could just use a regex to clean it up:

```
...css("backgroundImage").replace(/url\(['"]?([^\)'"]+)['"]?\)/, "$1")
```

Also, your css definition is wrong. It should be:

```
background-image: url(...);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: or even: `background: url(...) no-repeat;`. anyway in your regex why would you want to match quotes?

Comment: because it's valid to use `url('myfile.gif')` or `url("myfile.gif")`, and this handles each of those. no harm in being a bit more robust?

Answer (score 1):

You can access CSS properties from JavaScript pretty easily. Check this out for an in depth explaination: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript